# Custom file/folder permissions with S3FS?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ftp, sftp, s3fs

I have setup an SFTP server using OpenSSH. The home directory for users is `/sftp/%user`. I'm mounting an S3 bucket at `/sftp` using S3FS. The problem is that S3FS cascades user permissions down through it's directory structure, meaning:

1. I can configure files at `/sftp/*` to have these permissions `drwxr-xr-x  1 root root` which allow SFTP users to connect, but they cannot write to their home directories because they don't own them.

`s3fs nwd-sftp /sftp/ -o iam_role=sftp-server -o allow_other -o stat_cache_expire=10 -o enable_noobj_cache -o enable_content_md5 -o umask=022`

2. I can configure files at `/sftp/*` to have permissions `drwxrwxr-x  1 root sftpusers` so users can (in theory) write to their home directories, but the SSH protocol won't let them login because it considers these permissions incorrect (allowing members of a group write access).

`s3fs nwd-sftp /sftp/ -o iam_role=sftp-server -o allow_other -o stat_cache_expire=10 -o enable_noobj_cache -o enable_content_md5 -o umask=002 -o gid=501`

I can't figure out how to customize the ownership or permissions once a drive is mounted with S3FS. Is there a way to do this? How can I customize the users' home folders within the S3 mounted `/sftp` folder?

Comment: *"The problem is that S3FS cascades user permissions down through it's directory structure."*  I really don't understand this comment.  `sudo chown -v -R sqlbot /sftp/sqlbot` should make me the owner of the files and directories under my FTP home directory on s3fs the same as any other filesystem (or thing that acts like a filesystem).  Does this not work for you? If not, what version of s3fs is this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I'm using Version 1.79. I'm unable to change permissions normally. `sudo chown -v ec2-user:ec2-user /sftp/folder/` results in `chown: changing ownership of ‘/sftp/folder/’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: It needs to be mounted without `-o gid` or `-o uid`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I've tried mounting with many combinations, including `-o allow_other` and `user_allow_other` in the `/etc/fuse.conf` file and excluding `-o guid ###` and excluding `-o uid ###`. No matter what I do, I cannot `chmod` or `chown` folders and get this message `chown: changing ownership of ‘folder/’: Operation not permitted`. I am able to `chmod` and `chown` files, however, but that doesn't solve my problem of allowing users to upload to their home folders. The same problem exists if the folder was pre-existing in S3 and if I create a new folder with  `mkdir` after mounting.

Comment: Well, that's weird.  Unless something is broken, that should work.  It does work on my systems, but I don't know whether I have 1.79 running.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Who owns new folders you create after mounting the bucket and what is their file mode?  Can you `chmod` folders?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I control ownership of mounted folders with `-o uid ###`, `-o gid ###`, and `-o umask ###` but then settings are static. I've tried many combinations of settings with no change in behavior. I get the same error message when `chmod`-ing these folders `chmod: changing permissions of ‘folder/’: Operation not permitted`. If I only use `allow_other`, then `root` owns everything, and permissions are completely open on the mounted folder and completely closed on internal folders `d---------  1 root root`. Newly created folders get this `drwxr-xr-x  1 root root` - still not changeable.

Comment: Based on covos around the web suggesting permission issues were fixed a while ago, I've thought this might be a new bug in 1.79 as well.

Comment: He's just released s3fs 1.80... you might take a look, there have been something like 200 fixes that have accumulated since 1.79.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

> s3fs#  fuse
>   _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,use_cache=/tmp,umask=002,uid=1000
>   0 0

Example:

> s3fs#examples /home/ubuntu/s3bucket/examples fuse
>   _netdev,allow_other,passwd_file=/home/ubuntu/.passwd-s3fs,use_cache=/tmp,umask=002,uid=1000
>   0 0